# SharePoint Search no longer returns any results when item level permissions have been implemented on all list in site. Is this normal?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, search-results, sharepoint-search, item-level-permissions

After implementing item-level permissions on all lists and libraries in a site the SharePoint Search has stopped returning results. Is this normal behavior?

I was hoping and expecting the search to work but to only return results for items the user had permission to see but nothing at all gets returned.

After turning item-level permissions back off and running a full crawl the search returns results again.

The permissions were implemented on each list in `List Settings->Advanced Settings->Read items that were created by the user` & Create items and edit items that were created by the user.

The "Allow items from this list to appear in search results" is set to true.

The permissions for libraries were implemented by setting the same properties but using PowerShell as the setting isn't available in the UI for libraries.

The user account being used has a custom permission level that almost matches Contribute but with **Override List Behaviours** turned off as this bypasses the item level permissions.

If it matters, this is an on-premise SharePoint 2013 Foundation version.

Answer (score 0):

Not seeing any info from Microsoft on this issue. However, I have verified that users need at least **Read all items** permission on lists with unique/item-level permissions for search query to return items.